# Vector space axioms (addition result be in the space)

Tags: vector-spaces

My question might seem easy but it is confusing me. In "Linear Algebra Done Wrong" (also the same axiom list is given at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorSpace.html), it is not mentioned among the vector space axioms that the result of the addition and multiplication must be in the space. However, most sources mention this and I think it makes more sense. Is this requirement implied by the 8 axioms?

Thank you.

[Relevant part from LADW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R51OV.png)

Comment: This axiom does not follow from the others. In Mathworld, the first sentence says it specifically "A vector space V is a set that is closed under finite vector addition and scalar multiplication.", although I would have added it to the list of axioms

Comment: To me it sounds like the first sentence covers that.  "*$V$ is a set that is closed under finite vector addition...*" and we use the same $V$ later on.  "*In order for $V$ (our set closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication) to be called a vector space, the following (additional) conditions must hold...*"

Comment: My mistake, I did not see that part. However, LADW still seems to have omitted that. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Well, the book is called "Linear Algebra Done *Wrong*" ;)

Comment: It seems to me that the author might have intended the closure to be implied in how addition and multiplication are defined, noting that he didn't define what he means by addition or multiplication in the linked section.  As to your question "*Is this requirement implied by the 8 axioms*" the answer is no, but it could be implied by context and surrounding sections. Indeed, you can take a subset of an actual vector space and remove some elements, all of the later 8 axioms still work.  E.g. $(\Bbb R\setminus\{-3,3\},+,\times)$ where addition and multiplication defined as normal for $\Bbb R$.

Comment: It proves that linear algebra is actually done wrong from the very beginning in LADW.